# display an embedded document data model in mongoose in browser

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm using embedded document data model in mongoose and my data is like this

```
var firstuser1 = new user({userid: 'absj8d55',
  tokenid: 'akn178i3',
  media: [{mediaid: 'mid01',mediaurl:  'dl.ingrm.com/mid01'},{mediaid: 'mid03', mediaurl: 'dl.ingrm.com/mid03'}]
});
```

I save it and then I want to display it on my browser so I use this function:

```
app.get('/allmedia', function(req, res) {
user.find({},function(err, myuser) {
  res.send(myuser);
  //console.log(myuser);
})});
```

User is my model here:

```
var userschema = new mongoose.Schema({
userid: {type: String, unique: true},
tokenid: {type: String, sparse: true, default: null}},{
media: {
mediaid: String,
mediaurl: String
}
});
var user = mongoose.model('mydb', userschema);
```

U run this code but all I get is this:

> [{"_id":"5780e1e5797fc3181865686b","userid":"absd1234","tokenid":"akdndkdn12345678"}

It doesn't display the media!!

Where am i doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: **User is my model here.** Where?

Comment: @LazarevAlexandr Thank you for fixing my mistakes, I edited it, now if you could help me I really appreciate it.

Comment: In your model, media is an object but not an array.

Comment: @Saleem so how should I save my data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `userschema` constructor, you are setting `media` object as the second argument. Second argument in schema constructor is `options` object. Change this:

```
var userschema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userid: {type: String, unique: true},
  tokenid: {type: String, sparse: true, default: null}
},{
  media: {
    mediaid: String,
    mediaurl: String
  }
})
```

to:

```
var userschema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userid: {type: String, unique: true},
  tokenid: {type: String, sparse: true, default: null},
  media: [{
    mediaid: String,
    mediaurl: String
  }]
})
```

Also, as @Saleem mentioned, in your model `media` is an object, not an array. So change change schema to:

```
var userschema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userid: {type: String, unique: true},
  tokenid: {type: String, sparse: true, default: null},
  media: [{
    mediaid: String,
    mediaurl: String
  }]
})
```

Comment: oh Thanks, when I change all to object i get the error for this line:                ` media: {mediaid: 'mid01',mediaurl:  'dl.ingrm.com/mid01'},{mediaid: 'mid03', mediaurl: 'dl.ingrm.com/mid03'}
}`      unexpected token ' } '.    if I turn them all to array how can I reach media? or mediaid? the myuser.media didnt work!!

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. You should change schema to array, not the object you are trying to insert. Will fix it in my answer.